# Nginx: Change status code of error response

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have nginx to reverse proxy backend. I need to change status code of all 403 backend's responses to 401, preserving everything else (This is needed to make 3rd party client app work with backend)

My current configuration is

```
server {
  ...
  error_page 403 = @unauthorized;

  location / {
    ...
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
  }

  location @unauthorized {
    return 401;
  }
}
```

Problem with this configuration is that all original headers/content are lost. Is there a way to modify status code only, instead of responding with a whole new response? Or maybe get access to original response and copy everything from original response in @unauthorized?

Thanks.

Comment: Ouch, four years and no answer! Have you tried to get the contents of the `$body` variable and send it back? If all else fails, you could try to compile the [ngx_headers_more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module, which should allow you to change the headers at will while keeping the content untouched.